# Using HashMap to create complex JSON

Tags: java, json, hashmap, rest-assured

I have spent a few days googling this various ways and don't see any that give examples of using HashMap - instead they all refer to Jackson or GSON. I am not able to use these as they cause an issue in Jenkins that will not be addressed (basically everything is super locked down and the work place will not "open" up alternatives)

I have a JSON body that I am attempting to send to a create record API.

For simple JSON body the process is pretty straightforward:

Desired JSON:

```
{
    "owner": {
        "firstName": "Steve",
        "lastName": "Guy",
        "Hair": "brown",
        "Eyes": "yes"
        "etc": "etc"
    },
    "somethingElse": "sure"
}
```

would look like

```
Map<String,Object> jsonRequest = new HashMap<>();

Map<String,String> ownerMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Object, String> OwnerMap = new HashMap<Object, String>;
    OwnerMap.put("firstName","Steve");
    OwnerMap.put("lastName","Guy");
    OwnerMap.put("Hair","brown");
    OwnerMap.put("Eyes","yes");
    OwnerMap.put("etc","etc");
jsonRequest.put("owner", OwnerMap);
jsonRequest.put("somethingElse", "sure");
```

Easy enough

If the JSON gets slightly more complex, I can't seem to figure it out.. and again I **cannot** use any other dependency for this.

so if I have a JSON Body that I need to send :

```
{
  "customer": {
        "address": [
            {
              "address": "Blah"
             }
          ]
       },
   "anotherThing": "thing"
}
```

the same pattern does not work.

```
Map<String,Object> jsonRequest = new HashMap<>();

Map<String,String> ownerMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Object, String> addressMap = new HashMap<Object, String>;
    addressmap.put("address","Blah");
jsonRequest.put("address", addressMap);
jsonRequest.put("owner", OwnerMap);
jsonRequest.put("anotherThing", "thing");
```

returns as:

```
{
    "owner": {

    },
    "anotherThing": "thing",
    "address": {
        "address": "Blah"
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the JSON lib? and why not ask the author how to handle your case?

Comment: How are you converting the Hashmap to JSON if you are not using a library to do it? Or are you using some library other than GSON or Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to assume that the *inner* (for want of a better word) `Map`s need to be `Map<*, String>`, and that `Map` and `String` are the only things which `extend Object`.

Something like the following should work fine:

```java
Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Object> customer = new HashMap<>();

// Could make this a Map<String, Object>[] (array) depending
// on json library used...  You don't specify.
List<Map<String, Object>> address = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> innerAddress = new HashMap<>();
innerAddress.put("address", "Blah");
address.add(innerAddress);

customer.put("address", address);

json.put("customer", customer);
json.put("anotherThing", "thing");
```

Comment: To state it another way, your customer.address element is a JSON array. So you need to have a List of Maps for that element.

Comment: ^ That.  Another approach would be to make your json string as you want and _de_-serialise it and then inspect the output structure.  But again, without knowing the specific library, it's possible that it only serialises, and can't deserialise (although I'd be surprised).

Comment: thank you Crig and BeUndead! This worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it @CatAndPlantGuy. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem. 